# How to sort arguments in descending order in an orderless function

Tags: output-formatting, sorting

If I define an operator to be orderless

```
SetAttributes[CirclePlus,Orderless]
```

It puts the arguments into canonical sorting, i.e.

```
[In]:  CirclePlus[0, 2, 1]
[Out]: CirclePlus[0, 1, 2]
```

How can I make it, that it is sorted descendingly, i.e.

```
[Out]: CirclePlus[2, 1, 0]
```

I probably need to rewrite a specific output form, so it's fine if it doesn't work in StandardForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple ways to change the order of the argument sequence:

```
CirclePlus[0, 2, 1]
CirclePlus[0, 2, 1] // Sort
CirclePlus[0, 2, 1][[{1, 3, 2}]]
CirclePlus[0, 2, 1] // RotateLeft
CirclePlus[0, 2, 1] // Sort // Reverse
```

For descending order (// Sort // Reverse):

```
Remove@"Global`oPlus" // Quiet
CirclePlus // ClearAll
oPlus[x__] := CirclePlus @@ Reverse@Sort@List@x

oPlus[0, 2, 8, 1]
oPlus[0, 2, 8, 1] // FullForm
```

function oPlus is defined and used here. This is exactly what desired:
oPlus[0, 2, 8, 1] // FullForm gives CirclePlus[8,2,1,0]
without setting any attributes.

What happens setting attribute Orderless, for example one consequence is:

```
(* With *)    CirclePlus[0, 2, 1] === CirclePlus[0, 1, 2]  (* is True  *)
(* Without *) CirclePlus[0, 2, 1] === CirclePlus[0, 1, 2]  (* is False *)
```

For changing the order of the argument sequence in the output (this is a formating issue), there is no need to set or clear the attribute Orderless, (this is a change of functionalty of CirclePlus). The output format may be changed by Format[], e.g.

```
ClearAll@CirclePlus;
Format[CirclePlus[z__], StandardForm] := 
 Row[#, "\[ThinSpace]"] &@Riffle[Reverse@Sort@{z}, "\[CirclePlus]"]
CirclePlus[0, 2, 1]
CirclePlus[0, 2, 1] // FullForm
```

CirclePlus[0, 2, 1] // FullForm shows the argument sequence stays unchanged only formatting is different. Note: ClearAll is needed to get rid off the Format definition, this can't be done with Remove@"Global`*"

Comment: I get the error "Format::nosym: z__ does not contain a symbol to attach a rule to."

Comment: what os and version do you have? in mma 12.1 on win64 it works

Comment: I have an extra definition that causes it: `CirclePlus[a_]:=a` However, adding a `HoldPattern` around the first argument of Format is a fix. Thank you!